# How to create a field for project sale orders

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have fields for a quick access of the entities related to a project. For example:

```
class project(models.Model):
    _name = "project.project"
    _description = "Project"
    _inherit = 'project.project'

    production_order_ids = fields.One2many('mrp.production', 'project_id', 'Production orders')
    purchase_order_ids   = fields.One2many('purchase.order', 'project_id', 'Purchase orders')
    ....
```

I am trying to create a **sale_order_ids** in the **project.project** model. My first try did not work:

```
sale_order_ids   = fields.One2many('sale.order', 'project_id', string='Sale orders')
```

because because the field **sale.order**.project_id is of type **account.analytic.account**.

A **project.project** object inherits from **account.analytic.account**. This query should work ok if they would share the same Id, but they do not. So the navigation would be:

```
"project.project".analytic_account_id" -> sale.order".project_id
```

And the result would be the corresponding **sale.order**(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use a **computed field**:

```
sale_order_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order', compute='_get_sale_orders', string='Sale orders')

@api.model
def _get_sale_orders(self):
    for record in self:
        record.sale_order_ids = self.env['sale.order'].search([('project_id', '=', record.analytic_account_id.id)]).ids
```